# Only items from first Beautiful Soup object are being added to my lists

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

I suspect this isn't very complicated, but I can't see to figure it out.  I'm using Selenium and Beautiful Soup to parse Petango.com.   Data will be used to help a local shelter understand how they compare in different metrics to other area shelters. so next will be taking these data frames and doing some analysis.
I grab detail urls from a different module and import the list here.
My issue is, my lists are only showing the value from the HTML from the first dog.  I was stepping through and noticed my len are different for the soup iterations, so I realize my error is after that somewhere but I can't figure out how to fix.
Here is my code so far (running the whole process vs using a cached page)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from Petango import pet_links
headings = []
values = []
ShelterInfo = []
ShelterInfoWebsite = []
ShelterInfoEmail = []
ShelterInfoPhone = []
ShelterInfoAddress = []
Breed = []
Age = []
Color = []
SpayedNeutered = []
Size = []
Declawed = []
AdoptionDate = []

# to access sites, change url list to pet_links (break out as needed) and change if false to true.  false looks to the html file
url_list = (pet_links[4], pet_links[6], pet_links[8])
#url_list = ("Petango.html", "Petango.html", "Petango.html")
for link in url_list:
    page_source = None
    if True:
        #pet page = link should populate links from above, hard code link was for 1 detail page, =to hemtl was for cached site
        PetPage = link
        #PetPage = 'https://www.petango.com/Adopt/Dog-Terrier-American-Pit-Bull-45569732'
        #PetPage = Petango.html
        PetDriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/paulcarson/Downloads/chromedriver')
        PetDriver.implicitly_wait(30)
        PetDriver.get(link)
        page_source = PetDriver.page_source
        PetDriver.close()
    else:
        with open("Petango.html",'r') as f:
            page_source = f.read()
    PetSoup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    print(len(PetSoup.text))

    #get the details about the shelter and add to lists
    ShelterInfo.append(PetSoup.find('div', class_ = "DNNModuleContent ModPethealthPetangoDnnModulesShelterShortInfoC").find('h4').text)

    ShelterInfoParagraphs = PetSoup.find('div', class_ = "DNNModuleContent ModPethealthPetangoDnnModulesShelterShortInfoC").find_all('p')
    First_Paragraph = ShelterInfoParagraphs[0]
    if "Website" not in First_Paragraph.text:
        raise AssertionError("first paragraph is not about site")
    ShelterInfoWebsite.append(First_Paragraph.find('a').text)

    Second_Paragraph = ShelterInfoParagraphs[1]
    ShelterInfoEmail.append(Second_Paragraph.find('a')['href'])

    Third_Paragraph = ShelterInfoParagraphs[2]
    ShelterInfoPhone.append(Third_Paragraph.find('span').text)

    Fourth_Paragraph = ShelterInfoParagraphs[3]
    ShelterInfoAddress.append(Fourth_Paragraph.find('span').text)

    #get the details about the pet

    ul = PetSoup.find('div', class_='group details-list').ul  # Gets the ul tag

    li_items = ul.find_all('li')  # Finds all the li tags within the ul tag

    for li in li_items:
        heading = li.strong.text
        headings.append(heading)

        value = li.span.text

        if value:
            values.append(value)
        else:
            values.append(None)
    Breed.append(values[0])
    Age.append(values[1])
    print(Age)
    Color.append(values[2])
    SpayedNeutered.append(values[3])
    Size.append(values[4])
    Declawed.append(values[5])
    AdoptionDate.append(values[6])

ShelterDF = pd.DataFrame(
    {
      'Shelter': ShelterInfo,
      'Shelter Website': ShelterInfoWebsite,
      'Shelter Email': ShelterInfoEmail,
      'Shelter Phone Number': ShelterInfoPhone,
      'Shelter Address': ShelterInfoAddress
    })

PetDF = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Breed': Breed,
     'Age': Age,
     'Color': Color,
     'Spayed/Neutered': SpayedNeutered,
     'Size': Size,
     'Declawed': Declawed,
     'Adoption Date': AdoptionDate
    })

print(PetDF)
print(ShelterDF)
```

output from print len and print the age value as the loop progresses

```
12783
['6y 7m']
10687
['6y 7m', '6y 7m']
10705
['6y 7m', '6y 7m', '6y 7m']
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your help!

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values is global and you only ever append the first value in this list to Age

```
Age.append(values[1])
```

Same problem for your other global lists (static index whether 1 or 2 etc...).

You need a way to track the appropriate index to use perhaps through a counter, or determine other logic to ensure current value is added e.g. with current Age, is it is the second li in the loop? Or just append `PetSoup.select_one("[data-bind='text: age']").text`

It looks like each item of interest e.g. colour, spayed contains the `data-bind` attribute so you can use those with the appropriate attribute value to select each value and avoid a loop over `li` elements.

e.g. `current_colour = PetSoup.select_one("[data-bind='text: color']").text`

Best to set in a variable and test `is not None` before accessing with `.text`

Comment: thank you!  that got me going in the right direction.  I wound up redoing the pet variables similar to how you have it constructed above and how I'd done the shelter info. 
 (adding the is not None, thank you for the tip)  It's working as I'd expect with the values feeding the data frame.  next, on to doing some analysis. thank you again for the direction!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `find` method into `find_all()` in BeautifulSoup so it locates all the elements.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but I think that's not quite it.  I really only want the first one it finds in each of the soup iterations.  My issue is it appears to only be grabbing the values from the first pass through instead of replacing it (eg soup1, values, soup 2 values etc.)  I tried the find_all and it throws an error that there isn't another value after that first one which makes me think it's only going through one of the soup objects.  Thank you for the suggestion